# Vectorize this call to minimize_scalar

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have a pandas DataFrame, `df`, of point values in the form

```
     | X | Y |
     |-------|
     |x0 | y0|
df = |x1 | y1|
     |x2 | y2|
        ...
     |xn | yn|
```

I also have a `scipy.interpolate.Bspline` object, `bs`, from scipy.  What I want to do is, for each point (xi, yi) in `df`, find the *minimal* distance between (xi, yi) and `bs`.

At the moment I am running a for loop that does something like the following:

```
class DistanceFunctor:
    def __init__(self, point, spline):
        self.point = point
        self.spline = spline

    def __call__(self, t):
        return distance_between_points(self.point, self.spline(t))


result = []
for xy in df.iterrows():
    result.append(minimize_scalar(DistanceFunctor(xy, bs)).fun)
```

where `distance_between_points` is just the regular distance formula from mathematics.  In other words, I take a point, construct DistanceFunctor with the point and the spline, then run the `minimize_scalar` function on DistanceFunctor.  I do this for each and every point.  The results are correct, but it is *very* slow to do this for every point in my dataframe.

I was wondering if there was some way to vectorize this operation, since the spline is constant.  The only thing that changes each time in the for loop is which point I am using.

Thank you for your help, and if there is any more information that I can provide, please feel free to ask.

Note that the above code is not my exact code, but a stripped down code that I can display in this question.

Answer (score -1):

The fact that you're constructing an object for each pair of points you want to evaluate surely will slow things down. You might avoid using an intermediate representation and use a list comprehension instead.

```py
result = [minimize_scalar(distance_between_points(xy, bs)) for xy in df.iterrows()]
```

Comment: The distance functor is required because the minimize_scalar must evaluate the spline at various t parameters.